# Regex with negative look behind still matches certain strings in Scala

Tags: regex, scala

I have a text, that contains url domains in the following form:

```
[second_level_domain].[top_level_domain]
```

This could be for instance **test.com**, **amazon.com** or something similar, but not more complex stuff like e.g. **www.test.com** or **de.wikipedia.org** (no sub level domains!).

It could be that in front of the dot (between second and top level domain) or after the dot is an optional space like **test . com**, but this doesn't always have to be the case.

However what I don't want to match is if the second level domain and top level domain belong to an e-mail address like for instance **hello@test.org**. So in this case it shouldn't extract **test.org**

I wrote the following regex now:

```
(?<!@)(([a-zA-Z\d]+(?:-[a-zA-Z\d]+)*(?<!www))\s?\.\s?(com|net|org))
```

With the negative look behind I want to make sure, that in front of the second level domain shouldn't be an @. However it doesn't really do what I expected. For instance on the text **hello@test.org** it extracts **est.org** instead of extracting nothing. So, apparently it only looks at the first character when it checks if there is an @ in front. But when I use the following regex it seems to work on the text **hello@test.org**:

```
(?<!@)((test)\s?\.\s?(com|net|org))
```

Here I hard coded the second level domain, with which it works. However if I exchange that with a regex that matches all kinds of second level domains

```
([a-zA-Z\d]+(?:-[a-zA-Z\d]+)*(?<!www))
```

it doesn't work anymore. It looks like that the negative look behind is already used after the first character is matched and that it doesn't wait with the negative look behind until everything is matched.

As an alternative I could match a bit more and then use the groups afterwards to build my desired match, but I want to avoid that if possible. I would like to match it correctly immediately. I'm not an expert in regular expressions and apparently I have not understood look arounds properly yet. Is there a way to write a regex, which behaves like I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?:^|(?<=\s))((?:[a-zA-Z\d]+(?:-[a-zA-Z\d]+)*(?<!www))\s?\.\s?(?:com|net|org))
```

Add anchors to disallow partial matches.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/rK5lU1/34

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you suggest that I check that it starts at the beginning of a string with ^ and that it ends at the end of the string with $?

If yes, then it doesn't work for me since I have more text than that. For instance: **You can send foo.com an email to the address hello@test.org** Here I would like to extract **foo.com**, but not **test.org**. However with ^ and & it wouldn't match anything, would it?

Comment: Yes, it works! Awesome! Thank you very much for your help. I just forgot to mention, that also a space could appear in front of the @ or after the @. But when I use (?<=[^@]\s) it works. However I have to admit that I don't understand how it works. Isn't  (?<=[^@]\s) just the opposite of (?<!@\s)? However the first regex works and the latter not.

Comment: I would give your answer a positive vote, but unfortunately I cannot do it. :(

Comment: @bam098 we need not worry about `@` as we dont capture it.We just make sure there is a space behind whatever we capture.Also as we dont capture `@` we dont care about `email`. :)